# Prevent Google Maps from disabling input on error

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places Javascript API for street address autocomplete on a textbox on a webpage. However, some customers have reported errors where the textbox becomes disabled.

I haven't been able to reproduce it on my website, but I have found other people have reported the same thing. For example:
[Why does my autocomplete search fiels freeze when trying to pull cities from Google Places API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261023/why-does-my-autocomplete-search-fiels-freeze-when-trying-to-pull-cities-from-goo)

My questions are:

1. How can I reproduce a Google Maps error?
2. How can I catch these
   errors, and display an error message instead of disabling the
   textbox?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and Google have a function where you can get Global Places Errors so you reactivate the field there.

Example

```
function gm_authFailure() {
    //code

    document.getElementById('Address').disabled=false;
    document.getElementById('Address').placeholder="";

    console.log('General Error with Google Api ');
    return false;
}
```

Documentation :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=es-419
https://www.imaginacolombia.com